# ASP.NET Core Custom Validation Attribute Not Firing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, custom-attributes, validationattribute

I have a GET method in API Controller. I would like that method to be validated using custom validation attribute as below. However it's not getting fired for some reasons.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class CheckValidRoute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private readonly string _apiRoute;
        private readonly string _operation;

        public override bool RequiresValidationContext { get { return true; } }

        public CheckValidRoute(string apiRoute, string operation)
        {
            _apiRoute = apiRoute;
            _operation = operation;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
           //Validation logic here
        }
    }
```

### Controller

```
public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("production/{movieId}/Test")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ResponseModel<string>), 200)]
        [Authorize(Policy = SecurityConstants.PseudofilmAuthorizationPolicy)]
        [CheckValidRoute("production/{movieId}/Test", "GET")]
        public async Task<ResponseModel<string>> TestGet(long movieId)
        {
            return ResponseModelHelper.BuildResponse("Success", $"production/{movieId}/Test", "Test");
        }
    }
```

I am not sure what I am missing here.

-Alan-

Comment: Why do you think this code should be fired? You have some filter, that checks for this attribute? Have you read the docs? Also, this should be named `CheckValidRouteAttribute`.

Comment: The name is something I'd definitely check.  Move it above authorize to ensure that's notr getting in the way. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1#custom-validation for docs

Comment: @StevenMayer, thanks for the link, but title "**Model** validation in ASP.NET Core MVC" doesn't bother you?

Comment: I read Net Core Custom Attribute and his code is for that, so provided the code I used for that. I, myself, would probably have looked into using a different filter that ran earlier instead of the custom validation attribute: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#resource-filters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong base class to implement your attribute.
`ValidationAttribute` is used on `Models` to validate their property values. An example of this is the `Required` attribute.

In your case you want to implement an `ActionFilter`, which can be applied to a controller method and can perform validation before the method is called. An example for you would be:

```
public class CheckValidRouteAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly string _apiRoute;
    private readonly string _operation;

    public CheckValidRouteAttribute(string apiRoute, string operation) : base()
    {
        _apiRoute = apiRoute;
        _operation = operation;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;

        var method = request.Method;

        if (string.Compare(method, _operation, true) != 0)
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult("HttpMethod did not match");
        }
    }
}
```

In the `OnActionExecuting` method you can perform your checks against the `HttpContext.Request` object. I have left that as an exercise for you as I don't know your exact requirements :-)

After applying this attribute to your controller method, the `OnActionExecuting` will be called before the controller method is called so you can do your validation.

You can read more about ActionFilters [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#action-filters)